# Which one is faster numpy or pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I started learning data science and encountered the two python libraries numpy and pandas can anyone please tell what are the difference between them and which one is faster?

Comment: Read their documentation. If you want timing statistics, try timing them.

Comment: [https://www.javatpoint.com/pandas-vs-numpy](https://www.javatpoint.com/pandas-vs-numpy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas is an open-source, BSD-licensed library written in Python Language.
Numpy is the fundamental library of python, used to perform scientific computing.
When we have to work on Tabular data, we prefer the pandas module and when we have to work on Numerical data, we prefer the numpy module.
The powerful tools of pandas are Data frame and Series  whereas the powerful tool of numpy is Arrays.
Pandas consume more memory.Numpy is memory efficient.
Pandas has a better performance when number of rows is 500K or more.Numpy has a better performance when number of rows is 50K or less.
Indexing of the pandas series is very slow as compared to numpy arrays. Indexing of numpy Arrays is very fast.
Pandas offers 2d table object called DataFrame. Numpy is capable of providing multi-dimensional arrays.

For your question usually numpy is faster as it consumes less memory and otherwise choice between two largely depends on size of dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is preferred for Tabular Data and is built upon Numpy.

Numpy on other-hand is preferred for arrays & related numerical analysis.

These both are quite different in there approach and work. but Pandas can be considered little slower than Numpy however the actual speed will depend on implementation and overall data size.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy and Pandas are 2 very different libraries/modules with very different use cases.

NumPy is mainly used for performing various numerical computations and processing of the multidimensional and single-dimensional array elements.

Pandas provides high-performance data manipulation. It is built on top of the NumPy package.

Determining which one is faster solely depends on what tasks you are performing. But for Data Science it is a good thing to have a good grasp of both of these as majority of the time will be spent on making the data more useful.